# Populate a column in SQL Server by weekday or weekend depending on the datetime

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I am working on SQL Server, wherein I cannot update any existing column nor can I add any more data/ column to the data.

I have a column of `dttime (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)` which consists of the date time value against each entry.
I want to select the existing columns , and a new column as `wd` which will be populated as 'weekend' when the day of the week is either **Saturday** or **Sunday** and 'weekday' in case of other days

I am using the below query:

```
SELECT id, total,
case when dayofweek(dttime) in (1,7) then 'Weekend' else 'Weekday' end as wd 
from table_name
```

Please suggest where is the mistake here, or is there any alternative to this, in case I have more than two different things to populate in a similar way, based on another column.

Comment: Why do you think there is a mistake in your query?

Comment: @HoneyBadger `dayofweek` is not exist in the SQL Server, may be he got the error as `'dayofweek' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DATENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql) of `dw` or `weekday` to achieve your expectation:

```
SELECT id, total, 
       CASE WHEN DATENAME (dw, dttime) IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 'Weekend' 
       ELSE 'Weekday' END AS wd
FROM table_name
```

Also your first day of the week can be set by the [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql), so based on the DATEFIRST set value the integer value for Sunday and Saturday can change. So getting `DATENAME` for the `dttime` will not cause any confusion.

You can execute the below query to understand more in detail, `DATENAME` will always return the current day name, but `DATEPART` will return based on the `DATEFIRST`.

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST AS 'First Day', 
       DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) AS 'Today', 
       DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) AS 'TodayName';
```

If `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` returns `7`, then you can use

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, dttime) IN (1, 7) THEN 'Weekend' ELSE 'Weekday' END AS wd
```

Here `1` for Sunday and `7` for Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

You need `DATEPART` function. try this :

```
SELECT id, total,
case when DATEPART(dw,dttime) in (6,7) then 'Weekend' else 'Weekday' end as wd 
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
SELECT id, total,
case when DATEPART(dw,dttime) in (1,7) then 'Weekend' else 'Weekday' end as wd 
from table_name
```