# SQL Server procedure to display if date is a weekday or weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server

Messing around in SQL and I am VERY new so please excuse my freshness to this. I have created a procedure that accepts a date as an input and prints original, one year later, a week later and a day later. Now I'd like to get it to tell me if those dates are weekdays or weekends in the output. I know from 'Googling' it may have something to do with `DATETIME` or `DATENAME`. Hoping for some guidance from you guys. Thanks!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dates 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @startdate SMALLDATETIME;
    DECLARE @dateafteryear VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @weekafter VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @daylater VARCHAR(50);

    SET @startdate = GETDATE();
    SET @dateafteryear = DATEADD(YYYY, 1, @startdate)
    SET @weekafter = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @startdate)
    SET @daylater = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startdate)

    PRINT 'Original Date ' + CAST(@startdate AS VARCHAR);
    PRINT 'A year later ' + CAST(@dateafteryear AS VARCHAR);
    PRINT 'A week later ' + CAST(@weekafter AS VARCHAR);
    PRINT 'A day later ' + CAST(@daylater AS VARCHAR);
END
GO

EXEC dates;
```

Output:

```
Original date Jan 12 2015 4:47PM, **is a Weekday.**
A year later Jan 12 2016 4:47PM, **is a Weekday.**
A week later Jan 19 2015 4:47PM, **is a Weekday.**
A day later Sep 17 2018 4:50 PM, **is a Weekday.**
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899473/populate-a-column-in-sql-server-by-weekday-or-weekend-depending-on-the-datetime. That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I recommend a user-defined calendar table (denormalized) for this purpose with a `date` primary key. That will not only allow you to easily identify a date as falling on a weekday and weekend, but also non-business day (holidays) your organization defines. Add columns for other attributes like day of week, quarter, fiscal year, etc. You can find many examples with a internet search. One example: http://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATEPART` in SQL Server (`EXTRACT` in Standard SQL) with the `weekday` argument (which can be abbreviated to `dw`). Note that `weekday` and `dw` are both language keywords and not string values, like so: `DATEPART( weekday, @startDate )`

This function returns an `int` value from `1` to `7` corresponding to the day-of-week. Note that the actual day-to-number mapping depends on your `DATEFIRST` context value, as in the US Sunday is the first day of the week (`1` = Sunday) but in most of the world it's Monday (`1` = Monday). I recommend you specify `SET DATEFIRST` with your desired value before calling `DATEPART( weekday, ... )`.

So to tell if a date is a weekend or not, do this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Specify 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, ..., 7 = Sunday

CASE DATEPART( dw, @startdate )
    WHEN 6 THEN PRINT 'Saturday'
    WHEN 7 THEN PRINT 'Sunday'
    ELSE PRINT 'Weekday'
END
```

Documentation:

- `DATEPART`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- `SET DATEFIRST`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

**I'm sure this is a thought experiment**, but I never saw much value in PRINT.  Also I see a lot of repetition.

Perhaps a argument for brevity.  :)

**Example**

```
DECLARE @startdate SMALLDATETIME;
SET @startdate = GETDATE();

Select comment = Concat(prefix,dt,'. *** is a ',case when DateName(WEEKDAY,dt) in ('Saturday','Sunday') then 'Weekend' else 'Weekday' end,'.**')
 From  ( values ( @startdate                  ,'Original Date ')
               ,( DateAdd(YEAR, 1, @startdate),'A Year Later ' )
               ,( DateAdd(WEEK, 1, @startdate),'A Week Later ' )
               ,( DateAdd(DAY , 1, @startdate),'A day later '  )
       ) A (dt,prefix)
```

**Returns**

```
comment
Original Date Sep 16 2018  4:55PM. *** is a Weekend.**
A Year Later Sep 16 2019  4:55PM. *** is a Weekday.**
A Week Later Sep 23 2018  4:55PM. *** is a Weekend.**
A day later Sep 17 2018  4:55PM. *** is a Weekday.**
```

**Just for fun, If you actually want to PRINT**

```
DECLARE @startdate SMALLDATETIME;
SET @startdate = GETDATE();

Declare @Print varchar(max) = (
Select Concat(prefix,dt,'. *** is a ',case when DateName(WEEKDAY,dt) in ('Saturday','Sunday') then 'Weekend' else 'Weekday' end,'.**',char(10))
 From  ( values ( @startdate                  ,'Original Date ')
               ,( DateAdd(YEAR, 1, @startdate),'A Year Later ' )
               ,( DateAdd(WEEK, 1, @startdate),'A Week Later ' )
               ,( DateAdd(DAY , 1, @startdate),'A day later '  )
       ) A (dt,prefix)
 For XML Path('')
)
Print @Print
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DATEPART` function with `CASE WHEN` to check the day whether weekday or weekend.

- `Saturday = 1`
- `Sunday = 2`

and I would write a function `WeekDayOrWeekEnd` to check the day.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].WeekDayOrWeekEnd (@input datetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(250)

    SET @Result =CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,@input) IN (1,2) THEN 'Weekend' ELSE 'Weekday' END
    RETURN @Result
END
```

your PROCEDURE can use like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dates 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @startdate smalldatetime;
    DECLARE @dateafteryear smalldatetime;
    DECLARE @weekafter smalldatetime;
    DECLARE @daylater smalldatetime;

    SET @startdate = getdate();
    SET @dateafteryear = DATEADD(YYYY,1,@startdate)
    SET @weekafter = DATEADD(week,1,@startdate)
    SET @daylater = DATEADD(day,1,@startdate)

    print 'Original Date ' + CAST(@startdate AS VARCHAR)+' is a '+ [dbo].WeekDayOrWeekEnd(@startdate)
    print 'A year later ' + CAST(@dateafteryear AS VARCHAR)+' is a '+ [dbo].WeekDayOrWeekEnd(@dateafteryear)
    print 'A week later ' + CAST(@weekafter AS VARCHAR)+' is a '+ [dbo].WeekDayOrWeekEnd(@weekafter)
    print 'A day later ' + CAST(@daylater AS VARCHAR) +' is a '+ [dbo].WeekDayOrWeekEnd(@daylater)

END
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7bf307b9da3be61d156d5cdfde2e2ce3)

Comment: This is great, I created the function but when I try to call it in the Procedure I get back an error message ' WeekDayOrWeekEnd' is not a recognizable built-in function name.

Comment: added dbo.WeekEndOrWeekDay

Comment: @Sam I edit it, just add [dbo]. in front of function name